# Add two variables together/find

Tags: javascript, arrays

It works except when the subject unless the subject is the same name. Then I get the first date to the second subject that is the same.

I can't change the array since it's through API. **However can I make so somehow if the first date is already set on math, then it should add the second date to second subject? Now the second subject get's the first date**

```js
var subjects = [
  { name: "math" }, //The first
  { name: "sports" },
  { name: "math" }, //The second
  { name: "art" },
];

var subjectdates = [
  { name: "math", year: 2017 }, //first date
  { name: "sports", year: 2018 },
  { name: "math", year: 2019 }, //second date
  { name: "art", year: 2020 },
];

const addDates = subjects.map((classes) => ({
  subject: classes,
  end_subject_date: subjectdates.find((item) => classes.name == item.name),
}));

console.log(addDates);
```

Comment: I don't understand a thing. Why do you try to add the year to the first array if the second array already is the first array plus the dates?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: Can you tell what should the expected output look like? "... first date is already set on **math**" what is **math** here?

Comment: I think you want to get the answer [ { subject: "math", end_subject_date: 2017 }, { subject: "sports", year: 2018 },  { subject: "art", end_subject_date: 2020 },];
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on `subjectdates`, construct a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `key` is the `name` and the value is a list of the elements of this `name`.

Then, in the loop, to get the `end_subject_date`, you can use [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) to get the list of elements of this `name`, and [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to get and remove the first element:

```js
const 
  subjects = [ {name:"math"}, {name:"sports"}, {name:"math"}, {name:"art"} ],
  subjectdates = [ {name:"math",year:2017}, {name:"sports",year:2018}, {name:"math",year:2019}, {name:"art",year:2020} ];
  
const subjectDatesMap = subjectdates.reduce((map, item) => 
  map.set(
    item.name, 
    [...(map.get(item.name) || []), item]
  )
, new Map);

const addDates = subjects.map(classes => ({
  subject: classes,
  end_subject_date: (subjectDatesMap.get(classes.name) || []).shift()
}));
   
console.log(addDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same keys in arrays:

1. Sort array by keys:

```
    subjects = subjects.sort((a,b)=>a.name>b.name?1:-1);
    subjectdates = subjectdates.sort((a,b)=>a.name>b.name?1:-1);
```

2. Insert values by index:

```
    const result = subjects.map((s, i)=>
       ({ subject:s.name,  end_subject_date:subjectdates[i].year})  );
```